# C# RESTful Framework, not based on WCF

Tags: c#, rest

I'am looking for C# RESTful framework (best with json support), which is not based on WCF in any way. WCF requires me to create namespace reservations, and this is thing i'd like to avoid (i already tried Nancy). The thing is target PCs for my service are older Windows XP machines, where are registering tools missing (netsh has no http context).
Can anyone suggest me good solution?

Comment: I think [ASP.NET MVC Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is a good candidate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). it's really only an issue if you have a self hosted WCF service running **along side** IIS. Other then that, if you run inside IIS, you are the only thing listening to port 80, or you are listening to a different port, then you dont care about URL registration. you can also redirect the request from IIS to a different port on the same machine.

   1. personally I really prefer WCF to all other and currently more popular alternatives, it gives you the best flexibility , and although it has a pretty significant learning curve, once you are "on top of the curve" gives you, in my opinion, the best "features developed / time invested" ratio
   2. Excluding WCF, I think your best solution is this (as doan commented):[ASP.Net Web Api](http://www.asp.net/web-api) combined with [this](http://json.codeplex.com/) ([another site](http://james.newtonking.com/json) ) which is an open source project that microsoft pretty much adopted, and its all shown [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization)

bare links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://www.asp.net/web-api

http://json.codeplex.com/

http://james.newtonking.com/json

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization

Comment: Yep, i don't run the service inside IIS. I would also prefer WCF, however, installing tools in order to register reservations on more than 250 PCs (and in future even more) i find as a little extravagance. I am already using JSON.NET and i am familiar with it, so it should be a straightforward. Thanks.

Comment: you'll probably need this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api and here http://owin.org/
again, you can achive pretty much the same thing with WCF...